# How do I add Skeleton.css to my React app?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, es6-modules, skeleton-css-boilerplate

I mainly use React in React Native and now I am building a website, so I am having a little trouble implementing [skeleton.css](http://getskeleton.com/) in my React App.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/favicon.png">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <meta name="theme-color" content="#000000">
    <link rel="manifest" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/manifest.json">
    <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/skeleton/2.0.4/skeleton.min.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">

    <title>Urban Hero</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="root"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

I added the CDN link tag and expected to use the css clases using `className` in my components like so:

```
export class HomeComponent extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <div className="section hero"></div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

I do get the default CSS applied, fontFamily and so on. However the classes are not being applied. I tried copy pasting [this demo landing page](https://github.com/dhg/Skeleton/tree/gh-pages/examples/landing) and it just does not look the same. (Of course I changed class for className)

Is there any step that I am missing here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to rethink the architecture of your application. The HTML page you copied into this post doesn't make sense in a React application, which should be written in JSX components (most of the time).

There many architectural patterns for React, but I usually like to start with ES6 includes for child components and ES6 classes to extend `React.component`. You could use regular functions instead of classes (check the [React documentation on Functions vs Class components](https://reactjs.org/docs/components-and-props.html#function-and-class-components)). I'll wrap the children in a `<BaseLayout>` component that provides the base CSS to all the other components in the project.

To work with this architecture and include Skeleton CSS, I'd leverage a package manager - `npm install skeleton-css` or `yarn add skeleton-css`, depending on which one you are using with your project. Once you do so, you can add it in like any other ES6 include.

Example of this (assuming some structural components are made):

```
import React from 'react'
import PropTypes from 'prop-types'

// this might be different depending on your file system
import './skeleton.css'

import Header from '../Header/header'
import Footer from '../Footer/footer'
import Metadata from '../Metadata/metadata';

export default class BaseLayout extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <SiteContainer>
        <Metadata customTitle={ this.props.title } />
        <div>
          <Header />
          <div>
            { /* Child components will inherit the CSS */ 
              children 
            }
          </div>
          <Footer />  
        </div>
      </SiteContainer>
    )
  }
}

BaseLayout.propTypes = {
  children: PropTypes.node.isRequired,
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the info but it still does not solve my problem. I wanted to add a third party css lib into my project and installing skeleton-css wont work. To integrate the library I had to install `css-loader`

Comment: @WalterMonecke - same idea, just use the boilerplate I set up. You can add any module with npm/yarn. Just don't try to add it in as a dependency in the HTML file itself.

Comment: Thanks! Will try it out today :)

Answer (score -1):

Try Importing your css file in your React application.

Comment: I did this in App.js and did not work. It seems I have to 1. eject the App or 2. mess with the webpack.config file.

Comment: If it didn't work it really is webpack problem, have you ever tried using create-react-app module? You won't have any problems related to this in the future.